# Ruby on rails Issue using a function with bootstrap for a menu

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm having some issues with my jquery in ruby on rails, I try to call my function for my navbar but in keeps sending a message **"toogleClass is not a function"** I checked the code and I don't see the issue:

application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require activestorage
//= require_tree .
function toogleView(){
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
      $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('active');
      $('nav').toogleClass('active');

    });
}
```

them I make the call in my view:

_navigation.html.erb

```
<header>
  <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
  <div class="menu-toggle"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portafolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</header>
<script>
  new toogleView();
</script>
```

I will really appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 4):

`toogleClass` is not a valid function, but `toggleClass` is a valid function. "toggle" not "toogle".

Answer (score 0):

You use trigger to change class

```
function toogleView(){
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.menu-toggle').trigger('active');
    $('nav').trigger('active');
 });
}
```